# Login in django using popup-modal using Ajax.

Tags: ajax, django, modal-dialog

Html part:

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myBtn2").click(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal();
    });
});

function login_to_user(){

    var uname = document.getElementById('id_username');
    var pass = document.getElementById('id_pass');


  $.ajax({
              url : /login_user/,
              type : "POST",
              dataType : "json",
              data : {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}', 'uname':uname,'pass':pass},

              success : function(data){
                console.log(data.username);

              },
              error : function(data){alert(data.response);}
          });

  }
</script>
```

```html
Login:
<li id="myBtn2"><a href='#'><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> 
        Login</a></li>

<!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Login Modal content-->
       {% if error_message %}
                        <p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>
                    {% endif %}
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" style="padding:35px 50px;">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span> Login</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">

          <form id='for' class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" onsubmit="login_to_user()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
           {% csrf_token %}
             <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="id_username">
                                Username:
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input id="id_username" maxlength="30" name="username" type="text">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="id_password">
                                Password:
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <input id="id_password" maxlength="30" name="password" type="password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <input type="submit" value='Submit'class="btn btn-success" >
                            </div>
                        </div>
          </form>
        </div>
```

views.py

```
if request.method == "POST":
    if request.is_ajax():
        username = request.POST['uname']
        password = request.POST['pass']

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request,user)

                return redirect('home')
            else:
                return render(request, 'index.html', {'error_message':'Account Deactivaated'})
        else:
            return render(request, 'index.html', {'error_message':'Invalid Login'})
return render(request, 'index.html')
```

urls.py:`url(r'^login_user/$', views.login_user, name='login_user')`

The userlogin :username and password is not sent after form submission.The page freezes.The index page wont redirect to home.html as required.What is wrong, is it ajax sending data or what?

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to even use ajax, a simpler version can work. Try replacing your form with this one (keep the rest of the modal functionality):

```
<form action="/login_user" id='for' class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="id_username">
            Username:
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input id="id_username" maxlength="30" name="uname" type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="id_password">
            Password:
        </label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input id="id_password" maxlength="30" name="pass" type="password">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <input type="submit" value='Submit'class="btn btn-success" >
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Specifically note the updated name attributes, and the action method for the form.

In the view, you'd no longer need  the ajax check:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    username = request.POST['uname']
    password = request.POST['pass']
    ...
```

Hope this helps.